# Can I use "friend" instead of "befriend"?

Tags: spelling

Is it ok to say

> I want to friend you.

instead of

> I want to befriend you.

?

Comment: Please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like an example scenario, example sentences, and explain why you think each makes or does not make sense.

Comment: @Max Edited it, does it help?

Comment: Not really. Now it has become a question that can be answered by a dictionary, which is [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Why do you think they are interchangeable? Do you have a reference (like a dictionary entry) that says that you can?

Comment: @Max It is just a question by me and I don't have a dictionary, just answer if you know the answer and you'll get your 15 rep for it.

Comment: Please include a full sentence, such as: "Last night I went to a party and "*friended*" a great guy there" OR " A great guy *friended* me at a party last night" This will help users give you the best answer, a little extra effort and you will reap more rewards. That is to say, it's more likely that both the question and their answers will earn more than 1 upvote.

Comment: A very similar question was asked on our sister site, EL&U: [To friend vs. to befriend](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148263/to-friend-vs-to-befriend)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Interesting, but I generally don't see the difference between the two.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you want to see your sentences there, edit my question.

Comment: @TimSpeckhals, we do expect people do a little bit of research before they ask a question. And when somebody suggests ways of making a question more specific, it is up to you to follow up on it by providing references and examples that show **specifically** what you are concerned about. As Max said, a dictionary can tell you the difference between these words on their own, and Mari-Lou's link also addresses this issue. If you want more specific answers, you need to write a more specific question.

Comment: @JavaLatte I have looked trough the search of ELL, I'm sorry if you are having to Stack Exchange forums for literally the same thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will try to answer this as clearly as possible.

Generally the term friend is used as a noun, but in few exceptional circumstances, it can be used as a verb.

Look at the following definitions I took from Google:

**friend**

verb

verb: friend; 3rd person present: friends; gerund or present participle: friending; past tense: friended; past participle: friended

1.informal

> > add (someone) to a list of friends or contacts on a social networking website.
> >
> > "I am friended by 29 people who I have not friended back"

2.archaic

befriend (someone).

black English

have a sexual relationship with.

"the woman got married and you still used to friend with she?"

The first definition refers to online reference and can be used quite informally.

Clearly the other two definitions are not so quite Common (one being archaic).

**befriend**

That is the verb most commonly used to refer your context.

Again I would like to cite the definitions from Google:

befriend

bɪˈfrɛnd/

verb

verb: befriend; 3rd person present: befriends; past tense: befriended; past participle: befriended; gerund or present participle: befriending

> > act as or become a friend to (someone), especially when they are in need of help or support.
> >
> > "he makes a point of befriending newcomers to Parliament"

So I think, friend can be used as a verb, only online (other usage synonymous with befriend being archaic). Otherwise you need to stick to 'befriend'.

Hope these clarify things.

Comment: So you're saying this sentence: *I befriended a person I met at a party last night* is acceptable and idiomatic. And *She friended with another girl* is totally wrong, unless it's referring to an online friendship. Is that correct?

Comment: I can't say it's wrong. But the definitions and usage tell that particular usage is archaic.

Comment: If ***to befriend*** is listed as being archaic,  would you use this form in a normal everyday conversation?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A , I ll take the point made. And coming to your comment, why do you want it to be archaic too? In that case, I can use the alternate term (friend) if someone officially declares thats no more archaic and bring it to day to day use . Otherwise we will be at loss for a word for that isn't it? Since befriend becomes archaic, I can't use an already archaic term instead.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - *Befriend* is somewhat archaic, but sometimes there's just no other word that will do.  It's not *wrong* to use archaic words, you just have to realize that they may sound a little old-fashioned or formal.  The problem with "friend" is that it still doesn't mean exactly the same thing as "befriend".  We do have other phrases that mean more or less the same thing: you can *strike up a friendship* with someone, you can *make friends* with them, or you can simply *become friends* with them.

Comment: @stangdon *make friends* exactly, the easiest, and most common expression. Who mentioned anything about *wrong*? I was trying to suggest a more contemporary and commonplace expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Using "to *friend*" as a synonym for "to befriend" is outside my sphere of experience.  It's *possible* this is something young people actually say these days, but otherwise the only place it's acceptable to *friend* someone is on Facebook.  Which, as we know, is something quite different from "make friends with".   I'm also not comfortable with the accepted answer as it includes specious definitions.